# TikZ / pgfmath: How to get several numbered variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Is there a way to create several numbered variables (like `\x1, \x2,..`) in a loop?

BTW: I do not need to use `\usetikzlibrary{math}` if there is solution without the `math`-library.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math} 

\begin{document}
\foreach \N in {1,...,5}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{random(1,52)}  Test: \tmp ~ 
%
\tikzmath{\x\N = \tmp;}  % Does not work
\tikzset{ declare function={ x(\N) = \tmp; },    } % Does not work
}%%

\section{Does not work}
%\pgfmathprint{\x3} % Does not work
%\pgfmathprint{x(3)} % Does not work
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Everything you do inside the `\foreach` loop will be local to it and will be forgotten after it. Either use the for loop of tikzmath, the `.list` handler or a different loop implementation. The `declare function` won't work either because PGFMath would only overwrite each `x(\N)` function (and `\tmp` would also only hold the last definition). Is there a use case for this?

Answer (score 3):

The normal `\foreach` loop creates a group. Everything you do inside will be lost afterwards unless a global definition is done.

With the basic tools of PGFKeys and PGFFor we can just define some macros to be result of the `random` function. A `.list` uses `\foreach` internally (allowing the `...` notation) but executes the key not inside the loop's group.

To access these numbers, we use the `\cisNum` macro (which is just a different name then `\x`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath, pgffor, pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/cis/.cd,
  create random numbers/.style n args={3}{
    /cis/temp/.code=%
      \expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname cis_num_##1\endcsname{random(#1,#2)},
    /cis/temp/.list={#3}}}
\newcommand*\cisNum[1]{\csname cis_num_#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{687855}
\pgfkeys{/cis/create random numbers={1}{52}{1, ..., 5}}
\pgfkeys{/cis/create random numbers={53}{104}{6, ..., 10}}

\foreach \N in {1, ..., 5} {Test: \pgfmathprint{\cisNum{\N}}\quad}\par
\foreach \N in {6, ..., 10}{Test: \pgfmathprint{\cisNum{\N}}\quad}
\end{document}
```

### Output

> Test: 22   Test: 32   Test: 34   Test: 49   Test: 42
> Test: 60   Test: 53   Test: 65   Test: 91   Test: 83

Comment: Uiui.... I took yor tip and... see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Got it by using the math-library loop:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
  int \N; 
  for \N in {1,...,5}{%
  \x\N=random(1,52);     };%
}

Test:
\foreach \j in {1,...,5}{x\j =\x\j,~}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just wanted to edit my answer with something similar but got hung upon the fact that the `for` loop variable (`\N` in your case) needs to be declared but not the `\x` variable. I guess this is because [“each item is evaluated”](https://tikz.dev/library-math#sec-58.4).